# Unable to log into servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I try to join a Minecraft server online, all of them say: "failed to login: the authentication are currently down for maintenance". All the servers say that. How do I resolve this?

Comment: server for what?

Comment: For what game exactly ?

Comment: Server for minecraft

Comment: According to your error message, the authentication servers are down for maintenance.  Not sure what you expect us to do about that.

Comment: well they all say that. isn't that weird?

Comment: The authentication servers are a Mojang thing. Until they are fixed you won't be able to log into ANY servers.

Comment: how long will it take?

Comment: We have no way of knowing.  We're not Mojang.  They're down until they're back.

Comment: ok. So in the meantime, i will dance naked

Comment: also make sure you and the server have the latest version

Answer (score 4):

The 'Multiplayer session service' is currently down, that is why you can't login on any online server. Mojang are aware and are working on the issue. You can check https://help.mojang.com/ for the current status of the service. You could also follow @MojangSupport or @MojangStatus on twitter for updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a server owner and want to temporarily grant access to your world while Mojang's auth servers are unstable, you can modify the server.properties file to accommodate this. Change:

```
"online-mode=true"
```

to

```
"online-mode=false"
```

This skips the authentication attempts sent to the Mojang servers. Be warned though: this also means that others can impersonate anyone (including admins), so this would not be recommended on servers larger than just a small group of trusted friends. Don't forget to change the value back to 'true' when Mojang's auth servers come back online.